# Custom scrollbar for listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a task to create a custom scrollbar for list view and to my knowledge the way you can customize your scrollbar is very limited on android. Is it possible to achieve exact same result like this:
[image]

If so, can you point me to a good example, or at least tell me what should I look into?

[EDIT] Also when scrolling, I would like to be able to use the thumb icon.

Comment: FYI, ListView is itself scrollable widget.

Comment: You can declare `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` for your listview to make it fast scroll.

Answer (score 4):

At the activity level, you could specify various attributes to specify the scrollbars. For the given scrollbar, you might have to specify `scrollbarThumbVertical`, `scrollbarTrackVertical` attributes. The list of customizable attributes are specified in [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#scrollbarThumbVertical).

Comment: I tried those, but is there a working way to specify height and width for each thumb and track?

Answer (score 4):

Create these two xml file in drawable

scrollbar_vertical_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FF6600"
        android:startColor="#FF6600" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>


</shape>
```

scrollbar_vertical_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" /> 
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />    
</shape>
```

Use these two xml file in list_view.xml

list_view.xml

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:divider="#FF6600"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/listview_layout_animation"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
    android:scrollbarSize="3dip"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a theme in res/styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scroll_track</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroll_thumb</item>
</style>
```

`@drawable/scroll_track` and `@drawable/scroll_thumb` must refer either to nine patch images or to a shape drawables. Scroll track image is a background for the scroll bar. Scroll thumb is responsible for the scroll handle. Then just apply the theme either to whole application or to an activity within AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

you can make this like i explaind and also put the pic in drawable as u want.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's the same solution as in sriramramani answer. It doesn't work, because specified images are getting stretched.

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up using separate Seekbar next to ListView.

Comment: Visually, yes. I didn't had to implement it's functionality though, my job was only to apply the design and this was probably the only solution, other than doing interface with OpenGL (which wasn't an option for that project) or creating custom widget.

Comment: @SMGhost : can u please share how u created it with some piece of code

Comment: @Shruti Just put listview on the left and seekbar on the right. As simple as that. I didn't wrote any code that handles communication between those components, so it is irrelevant.

Comment: @SMGhost : thanks for replying but i was looking for that communication only