# Custom Listview scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollbar, android-scrollbar

I have found out that it is indeed possible to create a custom scroll bar for an android Listview. I would like to use the scroll bar, that is found in Google's Google Now Launcher, with initial letters of app names.

[image: Google Now Launcher Scroll Bar]

How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225987/custom-scrollbar-for-listview

Comment: Yes, I know that how to make a custom scrollbar, I am just wondering how to set the letter of the current items in it

Comment: It is not very difficult. Suppose that you divide your scrollbar into 26 segments, you can get your scrollbar position and then set the corresponding letter to it. What you see from the picture is the laucher, and it may have different way to control the initial letter. But the principle is  similar.

Comment: Okay. Thanks I will try it out.